# Why does setting up this basic structure in CakePHP expect a database connection?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to understand some fundamental aspects of CakePHP, I successfully completed [the  blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Blog.html) (I am doing the 1.3 version because the project I need to work on is a legacy CakePHP1.3 app), and just to test my skills I setup a new, bare bones model, view and controller under the same project with the structure and code below.

What I don't understand is when I run this via localhost/foo/info/, while the address loads, the page reports it is looking for a database table called 'foos'. If I add the table called 'foos', the page loads fine. **But what I don't understand is what would I have to do so I can run this same code independently of the database?** In other words, so it runs without any database table called foos. I don't understand where in the code below there is a request for a 'foos' table.

**/app/models/foo.php**

```
<?php
class Foo extends AppModel
{

}
?>
```

**/app/views/foo/info.ctp**

```
<!-- File: /app/views/foo/info.ctp -->

<h1>Info page</h1>

<p>This is an info page</p>
```

**/app/controllers/foo_controller.php**

```
<?php
class FooController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Foo';

    function info() {
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: because the blog needs a db?

Comment: I setup separate pages outside of the normal blog structure, just to see how to display static content (i.e. localhost/foo/info/ should just display <h1>Info Page</h1><p>This is an info page</p>. I understand it is in a project where one of the functions is to have code for a blog, but I'm just trying to understand how I would setup a completely independent static mvc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In model: `public $useTable = false;`

OR

In controller:  `public $uses = array();`

Further reading:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses